# Pythonic method for creating temporary copy of list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, copy

Is there a more Pythonic way for doing the following (please forgive the semi-pseudo code)?

```
from copy import deepcopy
# Create a copy of a list edit an element within it
# then run a function using the new copy of the list
actuallist = [some data]
answer = 0
for i in len(actuallist):
    temp = deepcopy(actuallist)
    temp[i] = temp[i] + something
    tempplus = DoSomething(temp)
    temp = deepcopy(actuallist)
    temp[i] = temp[i] - something
    tempminus = DoSomething(temp)
    answer += OneMoreThing(tempplus, tempminus)
```

Comment: You can copy a list doing `temp = actuallist[:]`

Comment: Is `DoSomething` doing something that requires an independent copy every time? And does it really need to be a deep copy? Usually, you could just use one list for the whole thing.

Comment: @simpel01 this won't do a deep copy. if the actuallist contains objects, only the references will be copied.

Comment: @user2357112 DoSomething does need an independent copy sadly as the calculation is relational to the elements within the list and the elements relation to each other.

Comment: The issue is that the unedited version of the list is required as the original values for each element are needed as only one element within the list can be edited at a time for the formula (performed by DoSomething) to hold true.

Comment: That doesn't require an independent copy every time. Just undo the change after calling `DoSomething`.

Comment: or pass a list slice into `DoSomething` like `DoSomething(actual[:i]+[temp]+actual[i+1:])` where temp is now just an element of your list rather than an independant copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `DoSomething` does not mutate the list, you could do this:

```
answer = 0
for i in len(actuallist):
    tempplus = DoSomething(actuallist[:i] + [actuallist[i] + something] + actuallist[i+1:])
    tempminus = DoSomething(actuallist[:i] + [actuallist[i] - something] + actuallist[i+1:])
    answer += OneMoreThing(tempplus, tempminus)
```

But regardless of whether we use a deep copy of the list or just slices, we should probably bundle that common functionality into a function:

```
def shift(target, index, shift_value):
    return target[:index] + [target[index] + shift_value] + target[i+index:]

answer = 0
for i in len(actuallist):
    tempplus = DoSomething(shift(actuallist, i, something))
    tempminus = DoSomething(shift(actuallist, i, -something))
    answer += OneMoreThing(tempplus, tempminus)
```

At this point we could rewrite that loop as:

```
answer = 0
for i in len(actuallist):
    answer += OneMoreThing(
        DoSomething(shift(actuallist, i, something)),
        DoSomething(shift(actuallist, i, -something))
    )
```

At this point you could actually rewrite this as a generator expression, using `sum` to do the summation.

```
answer = sum(OneMoreThing(
    DoSomething(shift(actuallist, i, something)),
    DoSomething(shift(actuallist, i, -something))
) for i in len(actuallist))
```

That's a bit much to do all at once though.  I'd probably suggest using another function.

I don't understand the nature of your functions based on the generic example names you gave, so I can't be sure how best to group this.  You could do something like this though:

```
def shift(target, index, shift_value):
    return target[:index] + [target[index] + shift_value] + target[i+index:]

def one_more_thing_for_index(actuallist, i, something):
    return OneMoreThing(
        DoSomething(shift(actuallist, i, something)),
        DoSomething(shift(actuallist, i, -something))
    )

answer = sum(one_more_thing_for_index(actuallist, i, something)
             for i in len(actuallist))
```

With these really generic names I think this actually might be less clear than your example.  However, I presume there are some logical names you could pick for your particular problem domain that would make this more self-documenting.